# How to setup modern Ring Network with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan

We're making some sort of LAN-Party with friends, and, due to various reasons, we want to setup the network in a way of a [ring network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_network). We of course all have modern machines with end-user network adapters; we also all run Windows 7 (in different versions - but the lowest is Home Premium I believe).

So, what's a way to set up this kind of network? The use cases and requirements for this would be:

- Support for standard laptop OEM LAN cards as well as cheap USB-LAN adapters (most laptops have only one LAN port, unfortunately)
- Support of games based on IP addressing (some may work with weird protocols, other may not)
- It should support internet connection sharing (most likely only one person will have shared internet connection)
- Minimal installation complication and configuration (I can configure every PC, but I'd like to keep my work as simple as possible. Preparing the easy script for everyone would be even better, bust most likely I will test anything myself anyway, so it's not a priority).

I'd like to know what I will need to set this all up properly, also, what are the caveats (special abilities LAN adapter should support -> how to check for them, etc.)

I am mostly concerned with the physical layout of cables. I don't want them to be concentrated in one point; instead, I want them to go around the room.

Comment: If you're just worried about tripping on a clutter in the middle of the room, then wouldn't using longer Ethernet cables (and a little bit of cable organization) to run lines to the central switch (which sits someplace not actually in the middle of the room) be easier?  :)

Comment: "[Misconceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_network#Misconceptions) - "Token Ring is an example of a ring topology." 802.5 (Token Ring) networks do not use a ring topology at layer 1. As explained above, IBM Token Ring (802.5) networks imitate a ring at layer 2 but use a physical star at layer 1." -- I edited your question to reflect just a "Ring network", to avoid (further) confusion. :)

Comment: If you want a true modern ring network then go FC-AL. Do note that it won't be cheap though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can do this by simply bridging the two network adapters on each machine, including the one connected to the router / internet gateway.

1. Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click the two network adapters
4. Right-click on one and select "Bridge Connections"

It's been a while since I looked at what exactly a token-ring network was, though. As best I can tell, this still won't be a *real* token-ring network (you're just using standard ethernet with daisy-chained bridges instead of a hub or switch); A proper token-ring network would require the appropriate hardware.

Comment: Well, token-ring-like is sufficient. I meant physical topology rather than hardware "implementation".

Comment: It's certainly worth a try, though. I will try that, if it's indeed enough, I will accept it. I want to give others at least 24 hours, though ;)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Side note: Don't actually make it a ring by connecting the first computer to the last one. The ethernet gods will smite your network with a congestion that renders it inoperable as packets collide *with themselves*.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Token Ring's physical topology was "star wired", so just plug your ethernet cables into a central ethernet switch and you have the same physical topology.

Comment: Well, I want it the other way around. I want the cables to go round the room rather than concentrate in one point.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm presuming this is all just for the fun of it? Doing this *will* result in a lot of traffic on the network, delays, and congestion, quite possibly resulting in poor network performance.

Comment: Uhm, no. It's to avoid clutter and single point of tripping introduced by switch. And I believe it will be better than wifi anyway

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Taping the cables to the floor with ducttape or similar is going to be far less headache then trying to configure this setup, or resetting it afterwards.

Comment: Let me be the judge of that